# Is there a way to get NSURL of all the images in iphone without using ALAsset

Tags: iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am new to iphone - objC et al. I wanted to know if there is a way by which I could get all the NSURL and filename of the images files in an iphone without making use of ALAsset ?

In the current code - it is done like below. And I see the time it takes to loop 1100 images is like 14 seconds. Is there a better way to get url,filename quickly, please let me know.

```
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsGroupType type = m == 2 || m == 1 ? ALAssetsGroupAll : ALAssetsGroupLibrary;

    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:type usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop)
     {
         if (group)
         {
             [group setAssetsFilter:m == 1 ? [ALAssetsFilter allVideos] : [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
             [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset* asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL* innerstop)
              {


                  if (asset)
                  {
                      @autoreleasepool
                      {
                          if (!initialized)
                          {
                              *innerstop = YES;
                              return;
                          }

                          /***************************************************************************************/



                          ALAssetRepresentation* defaultRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

                          if(defaultRepresentation)
                          {
                              //NSLog(@"defaultRepresentation for %@", [[defaultRepresentation url] absoluteString]);
                              long long size        = [defaultRepresentation size];
                              NSURL*    url         = [defaultRepresentation url];
                              NSString* fileName    = [defaultRepresentation filename];
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to make sure: have you profiled that 14 seconds by logging `[NSDate timeSinceReferenceDate]` or using Instruments, or by presenting any widgets on the device? If the latter have you obeyed the UIKit main thread rules?

Comment: @tommy : I'm using NSDate

Comment: @jonathan : app acts on these URL to read and post process images. And it waits awfully long to ve all of these information.

Comment: Yes, but *why* do you want to process *all* the user's images? What's the goal here? Some sort of funny photo app?

Comment: ios experts anyone ? can think of a better idea 
@JonathanGrynspan: more or less mate ;)

Comment: Okay, why do you want to process every image all at the same time? Why not when the user selects a specific image?